# Android SQLite first use: Error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I know, there are a lot of answers already. But I'm a newbie on using SQLite yet and I tried what those answers say but nothing works.

It says my column id doesn't exist but it does exist:

```
public class SQLite extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "OMDBAPI";

// Films table name
static final String TABLE_FILMS = "films";

// Contacts Table Columns names
static final String KEY_TITLE = "Title";
static final String KEY_YEAR = "Year";
static final String KEY_RELEASED = "Released";
static final String KEY_RUNTIME = "Runtime";
static final String KEY_GENRE = "Genre";
static final String KEY_DIRECTOR = "Director";
static final String KEY_WRITER = "Writer";
static final String KEY_ACTORS = "Actors";
static final String KEY_PLOT = "Plot";
static final String ID = "_id";

public SQLite(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_FILMS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_FILMS +"(" +
            ID + "integer primary key autoincrement," +
            KEY_TITLE + " TEXT, " +
            KEY_YEAR + " TEXT, " +
            KEY_RELEASED + " TEXT, " +
            KEY_RUNTIME + " TEXT, " +
            KEY_GENRE + " TEXT, " +
            KEY_DIRECTOR + " TEXT, " +
            KEY_WRITER + " TEXT, " +
            KEY_ACTORS + " TEXT, " +
            KEY_PLOT + " TEXT" +
            ");";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_FILMS_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_FILMS);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);

}
}
```

And I try to populate this on a listview:

```
public class Query extends Activity {

        private ListView list;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.list_view);

            DBController crud = new DBController(getBaseContext());
            Cursor cursor = crud.loadData();

            String[] titles = new String[] {SQLite.ID, SQLite.KEY_TITLE};
            int[] idViews = new int[] {R.id.idnumber, R.id.grid_title};

            SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(),
                    R.layout.adapter_layout,cursor,titles,idViews, 0);
            list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
}
```

This is my DB CONTROLLER (Newbie mistake? Should I put the ID here too?):

```
public class DBController {

    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private SQLite bank;

    String success = "Film saved.";
    String failed = "There was a problem saving the movie.";

    public DBController(Context context){
        bank = new SQLite(context);
    }

    public String insertData(String title, String release, String year, String writers,  String actors, String director, String genre, String plot, String runtime){
        ContentValues values;
        long result;

        db = bank.getWritableDatabase();
        values = new ContentValues();
        //  Insert values
        values.put(SQLite.KEY_TITLE, title);
        values.put(SQLite.KEY_YEAR, release);
        values.put(SQLite.KEY_RELEASED, release);
        values.put(SQLite.KEY_YEAR, year);
        values.put(SQLite.KEY_GENRE, genre);
        values.put(SQLite.KEY_DIRECTOR, director);
        values.put(SQLite.KEY_WRITER, writers);
        values.put(SQLite.KEY_ACTORS, actors);
        values.put(SQLite.KEY_PLOT, plot);
        values.put(SQLite.KEY_RUNTIME, runtime);

        result = db.insert(SQLite.TABLE_FILMS, null, values);
        db.close();

        if (result ==-1)
            return failed;
        else
            return success;

    }

    public Cursor loadData(){
        Cursor cursor;
        String[] fields =  {bank.KEY_TITLE,bank.KEY_RELEASED};
        db = bank.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = db.query(bank.TABLE_FILMS, fields, null, null, null, null, null, null);

        if(cursor!=null){
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        db.close();
        return cursor;
    }
}
```

Can someone help me find out why it says I don't have an ID column?

(Why are ppl downvote the post? I thought Stack Overflow was to help idiots like me =P)

Comment: I think cursor will become invalid after closing database in `loadData()`

Comment: This method isn't used in the code yet. I prob should delete it right?

Comment: I see `Cursor cursor = crud.loadData();` in Query activity

Comment: Oh my bad. So what I should do with the cursor?

Comment: Remove `db.close();` line from `loadData()` method

Comment: Shouldn't I modify this too: String[] fields =  {bank.KEY_TITLE,bank.KEY_RELEASED}; to String[] fields =  {bank.ID,bank.KEY_RELEASED}; ?

Comment: Yes, you use `ID` and `KEY_TITLE` in your adapter (`titles` variable). So the cursor should have the same fields – ID and KEY_TITLE. Either change  the query or the `titles` variable.

Comment: OMG I LOVE YOU Sergey!!! You made my day mate!!! Everything worked.

Comment: You are welcome! :) Next time please add full exception stacktrace to questions.

Comment: Yeah, rookie mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have `_id` column, you have  `_idinteger` because you forgot to put a space in the CREATE query. Change the line

```
ID + "integer primary key autoincrement," +
```

to

```
ID + " integer primary key autoincrement," +
```

Comment: Still having the error with the space =/. ID + " integer primary key autoincrement," , even tried ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " (space after autoincrement).

Comment: Have you increased the DATABASE_VERSION? Otherwise it will not create the new field

Comment: Yes. You already have database with `_idinteger`. Increase DATABASE_VERSION or just uninstall application and try again.

Comment: Sry, newbie question, you mean on the declaration private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1; or other place? I'm sure I didn't increased the database version tho.

Comment: Didn't worked but, that's ok. Thanks for the help tho. I will just have to study more.

Comment: @BlitzkriegBlue Probably, you didn't implement `onUpgrade()` method. Did you try to uninstall application?

Comment: I implemented tho. And did the uninstall. Maybe is the way I'm trying to access the list view. After saving I can click on a FAB to try to go there but it doesn't work. Uploaded the update and my db controller. Prob I should edit the DB Controller to add an ID too?

Answer (score -2):

You can use [baseColums](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/BaseColumns.html) interface that provides a primary key field (called `_ID`)
An [example from google](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html)

Comment: Thanks, will check it out.